# Some emails not being sent using play mailer plugin

Tags: scala, email, playframework, akka

I have an application in Scala and there I use [play mailer 6.0.1](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) to send out emails to about 20 - 30 people. I am using [akka](https://akka.io) in the backend to schedule the mails at a specific time (precisely 10 AM on a Tuesday) and it sends a mail to about 20 - 30 people one by one. Almost all the mails go through perfectly except 1 or 2. here's the error message I get:

```
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1469)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer$$anon$1.send(SMTPMailer.scala:14)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(CommonsMailer.scala:21)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer.send(SMTPMailer.scala:24)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPDynamicMailer.send(SMTPDynamicMailer.scala:8)
    at actors.EmailActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(EmailActor.scala:36)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:513)
    at actors.EmailActor.aroundReceive(EmailActor.scala:27)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2324)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2311)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1351)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:257)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1459)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer$$anon$1.send(SMTPMailer.scala:14)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(CommonsMailer.scala:21)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer.send(SMTPMailer.scala:24)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1555)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:71)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2322)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2311)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1351)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:257)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

I have the following configuration:

```
play.mailer {
  host = "smtp.gmail.com"
  port=587
  ssl=no
  tls=yes
  user = "USERNAME@EMAIL.COM"
  password = "PASSWORD"
  debug = no
  timeout = 60000
  connectiontimeout = 60000
  mock = false
}
```

Any insight with the above error will be very helpful. Please do ask for anything that you think is necessary to gain knowledge of the root of the above error.

Comment: May be you are crossing rate limit for gmail SMTP server requests. Please rate limits. You may need to implement a queue mechanism to stay withing limits